# Monkeys have long tails/tail

Tags: singular-vs-plural

What should come in here: tail or tails?

> Monkeys have long tails.
> Monkeys have long tail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*The monkey has a long tail*" and "*monkeys have long tails*" seem to me the best options.

"The monkey has a long tail" is used when speaking about monkeys in general AND when there is only one monkey under consideration.

"Monkeys have a long tail" might be possible but it's a bit awkward: it sounds as if they're sharing it.

"Monkeys have long tail" doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. English is a language developed by low IQs.

Comment: Our language-developers were poorly-paid. Most were barely literate. Thanks for the insult.

Answer (score 0):

*Monkeys have long tail* is not grammatical.

The normal form is

> Monkeys have long tails.

but

> Monkeys have a long tail.

is also possible.

I don't find any difference in meaning between these two.

Comment: The difference is that the second excludes any monkey with more than one tail (at least from being a typical monkey).  We wouldn't say that kitsune have *a* long tail, since they typically have up to nine each.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan but since monkeys don't have multiple tails, it's fine.